# using ternary operator in a string for serverless yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, serverless

I'm using serverless for AWS deployments and have an issue where we have named one of our Elastic Search resources "prod-logs" on production and "nonprod-logs" on UAT.  I have the variable `${opt:stage}` available in my serverless.yml to tell if something is on **prod** or **UAT**.

How can I use `${opt:stage}` within my *iamRoleStatements* to be able to output `arn:aws:es:${aws:region}:${aws:accountId}:domain/nonprod-logs/*` or `arn:aws:es:${aws:region}:${aws:accountId}:domain/prod-logs/*` based on the environment?  Or more specifically, how do I omit **non** when `${opt:stage}` is **prod**?

my yaml looks like this:

```
provider:
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Resource: arn:aws:es:${aws:region}:${aws:accountId}:domain/nonprod-logs/*
      Action:
        - es:ESHttpDelete
```

I've seen that you can use a ternary operator, but i'm not sure how you might use it in the middle of a string like:

```
Resource: arn:aws:es:${aws:region}:${aws:accountId}:domain/${!e ${opt:stage} = 'prod'? '': 'non'}prod-logs/*
```

Comment: There is nothing in the YAML specification that refers to (ternary) operators, so your title and tagging do not make much sense. You might as well  have added tags [tag:ascii] and [tag:utf-8]

Comment: One option is the [serverless-plugin-ifelse](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-ifelse). Another is to use native intrinsic functions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67278337/271415)).